# In Go, why isn't the stringer interface used when casting to string?

Tags: string, go, type-conversion

```
package main

type foo struct {
    bar string
    baz string
}

func (f foo) String() string {
    return f.bar + " " + f.baz
}

func main() {
    f := foo{"hello", "world"}
    v := string(f)
}
```

This outputs `main.go:14: cannot convert f (type foo) to type string`.

So it would seem that casting something to a string does not look at the stinger interface. My guess is that this is because casting is implemented on a lower level than the stringer interface and it's impossible/hard to mix the two, but I'm not sure. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Also, since this is not possible, what would be idiomatic way to convert my struct to a string in this case? Do I just call `.String()` myself, or `fmt.Sprintf("%s", f)`, or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no *casting* in Go, there is type [Conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) and [Type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

What you're doing (`T(Expression)`) is a conversion and it has strict rules when it can be used and what the result will be.

There are specific rules applied to [Conversions to and from a string type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type). So what you want cannot be achieved with type conversion.

The simplest and preferred way would be to call the method yourself:

```
v := f.String()
```

`fmt.Sprintf()` would be just an unnecessary overhead and complication if your `struct` already implements `Stringer`. But if you don't have guarantee for this, then yes, `fmt.Sprintf()` would be the general way.

You could ask why?

In the specification level the type conversion expression is not defined as the result of a custom/user made function or method. The `Stringer` interface (`type Stringer interface{String() string}`) is not even a built-in type in contrast to the [`error`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error) interface.

But despite the fact that `Stringer` is not a built-in type, it is still present in some packages (for example in [`fmt.Stringer`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer)) and is checked by various methods or functions (e.g. [`fmt.Printf()`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) and relatives).

Comment: `error` is the *only* builtin interface. `Stringer` is the more-normal case.